# Issue with Selenium click method in Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium

I have come across an issue with click on chrome browser. I have used this code which was suggested here:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick)); 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

But when I try to fill a form, it doesn't seem to click on a field which has calendar pop up. The same code works well in Firefox driver. The error that occures is the following:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element 
(Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.86).
```

I am using the latest version of chromedriver.exe. I am using ID to click on the field. 
Could someone help me to resolve this.?.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the site? If you don't mind ofcourse.

Comment: `executeScript` seems confusing. Why dont you click element by selenium like `elementToClick.click()`?